# Find all values $c$ such that $(x+1)/(x^2+2cx+4)$ has domain R

Tags: calculus, rational-functions

Word for word:

> Find all values of $c$ such that $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+2cx+4}$ has a domain **R**

---

I really don't know where exactly to start. I'm not sure what it means by "a domain **R**"

Comment: A domain $\mathbb{R}$ means a domain of "all real numbers," that is, $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: Actually my book wrote it with just a bold "R". I know what that symbols means but I just wanted to be accurate. That was most of my confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function will not be defined if the denominator is zero. You need that: $$x^2 + 2cx + 4 \neq 0$$
for any $x \in \Bbb R$. Which value of $c$ does this? Which value of $c$ makes that polynomial have no real roots? Which value of $c$ makes $\Delta < 0$ there? Now it's on you (;

Comment: Ok that's actually what I thought it meant but wasn't sure because it was just a bold R. So if I'm right I just solve for "the discriminate is less than 0"?

Comment: Yes. If the discriminant is less than $0$, then the polynomial does not swap signs - it stays always negative, ou always positive. In particular, it is never zero, which is what we need.

Answer (score 0):

We have $d(x)=x^2+2cx + 4 = (x+c)^2 +4-c^2$. Since $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}  d(x) = \infty$, we must have $d(x) >0$ for all $x$ in order for $f$ to be defined on $\mathbb{R}$ (otherwise $d(x) = 0$ for some $x$, and $f$ would be undefined).

Since the minimum value is, by inspection, $d(-c)=4-c^2$, we require $|c| < 2$.